# Atomic system satisfying a simple level scheme

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, ion-traps

I have a simple two level system with an allowed dipole transition between the levels. The top level is also allowed to decay to another third level (looks a bit like a lambda system). 
Could someone please tell me what atomic system could be best applied to this model (and what are the 3 levels). I need an ion that can be trapped and prepared in a superposition of the two qubit states, furthermore I need the decay constant from the upper level to the third level to allow for a slow decay (more than a few nano seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barium ions are used in ion traps and have a similar energy level structure to what you are referring.  The ground state is the $6^2\text{S}_{1/2}$ and the excited state is the $6^2\text{P}_{1/2}$ driven at $493.6\ \text{nm}$.  There is a decay down the metastable $5^2\text{D}_{3/2}$ with a relatively high branching ratio though (3:1 ground state to metastable state) at $649.9\ \text{nm}$.  The lifetime of the excited state to the ground state is $\sim 10\ \text{ns}$ and the lifetime to the metastable state is $\sim 32\ \text{ns}$.

I should note that for any fixed polarization of the repump laser, there will be dark states present in the metastable state unless an external magnetic field is applied, so I'd read a bit more about that depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I can't seem to find the level scheme you are referring to.  EDIT: found it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, sorry I didnt get your first message, I wasnt awake yet :), glad you found it.